# Efficiency difference between 2 linear line search in Python

Tags: python, coding-efficiency

I have a question regarding the difference in efficiency when doing list search. Why is there a difference between these two?

```
test_list= [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50]
```

The first one -

```
def linearSearch(A,x):
    if x in A:
        return True
    return False
```

The second one -

```
def linearSearch_2(A,x):
    for element in A:
        if element == x:
            return True
    return False
```

Testing them

```
%timeit linearSearch(test_list, 3)
438 ns ± 5.86 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit linearSearch_2(test_list, 3)
1.28 µs ± 7.05 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

The difference remains when I use a much larger list. Is there any fundamental difference between these two methods?

Comment: The 2nd snippet is running in constant time, because there's a `return` statement in the loop. It stops after the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks Rawing! Just realised I had a typo in my code which leads to the return statement in the loop for the 2nd snippet. I corrected it but the issue persists.

Comment: The first one is faster because it's implemented in C, while the second one is implemented in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although in theory, these should complete in the same time, Python's `in` operator is written to work at raw `C` level so completes much faster than writing your own `for-loop` in Python.

However, if you were to translate the second snippet into `C`, then it would out-perform the first snippet in Python as `C` is much more low-level so runs faster.

---

*Note:*

The first function is pretty much useless as it is identical to:

```
def linearSearch(A,x):
    return x in A
```

which is clear now that whenever you would call it, you could instead just write directly: `x in A` to produce the same result!

---

Out of interest, I wrote the second snippet in `C`, but to make timing more exaggerated, made it do the whole thing `1000000` times:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void main(){
    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (int s = 0; s < 1000000; s++){
        int x = 3;
        int a[25] = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50};
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
            if (i == x) break;
        }
    }
    printf("completed in %f secs\n", (double)(clock() - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

which outputted:

```
completed in 0.021514 secs
```

whereas my modified version of your first snippet in Python:

```
import time
start = time.time()

for _ in range(1000000):
    x = 3
    l = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50]
    if x in l:
        continue;

print("completed in", time.time() - start, "seconds")
```

outputted:

```
completed in 1.1042814254760742 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks. Good to see the numbers.